# Are OSGI framework properties mapped to system properties

Tags: osgi

Do OSGi frameworks modify the result of calling `System.getProperty` to include the values supplied to the framework at framework launch?

That is, the properties passed into a call like:

```
factory.newFramework(configProps);
```

available to `System.getProperty`? The reason is the desire to control 'jboss logging' without actually setting a global system property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

That said. If you get a property from the framework with BundleContext.getProperty than you can access System properties if not shadowed by the configProps.

Comment: Thanks. I hate jboss.